# Jquery Load more on Scroll Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little issue with the following code, it's working fine, however, the only problem is that when someone scrolls down a few times while the data has not been loaded, it creates problems such as it loads the same data twice or it skips some part, etc.. Any help would be greatly appreciated to control the speed of this.

```
var num = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        num = num + 20;
            $.get('load_data.php?load=' + num, function(data){ 
                $('#result').append(data);
        }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to set a flag on a waypoint.

```
var flag = false;
var num = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){      
        if(!flag){
            num += 20;
            $.get('load_data.php?load=' + num, function(data){ 
                 $('#result').html(data);
                 flag = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This would only fire the loaded data once.
This could be fired at waypoints on specific points on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, however, when I put the above code, there is still problems, i.e it loads 20 rows then after that it loads 20 new then 20 old, etc.. :( maybe it has something to do with the var num.

Comment: Added an edit to the code.  Try using the increment inside the if statement.  Also, so we are not appending onto the old HTML, try replace the loaded nodes with the html() function.  Let me know how this works

Answer (score 1):

This solved it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var num = 0;
var a = 1;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

    if (a == 1) {
        a = 2;
        num = num + 20;
                $.get('load_data.php?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&load=' + num, function(data){ 
                        $('#result').append(data);
                         flag = true;
                         a = 1;
                });
    }

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good glad to hear it.  It looks to be along the same principle I was using above.  Cheers.